# what are the differences between package installers?

Tags: apt, aptitude

I have just started using Linux Mint and I have come across multiple ways to install packages from the command line: apt-get, aptitude, gdebi so far. Can someone explain what the major differences between them are?

Comment: Just see this here.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/309113/what-is-the-difference-between-dpkg-and-aptitude-apt-get

Answer (score 1):

Heads up: this question is quite based on opinion. It all depends what you need.

They all do basically the same job (except dpkg, which doesn't install the other packages that a package depends on), but aptitude appears to have more features, none of which I regularly used when I had Mint, and apt has Super Cow Powers.

GDebi is a little different though. It's for installing deb packages you download from the internet, and it has a nice little GUI for installing the packages. The biggest difference between installing packages from GDebi and dpkg -i is that GDebi *does* install dependencies, so that takes a lot of time off using dpkg.

I also quite like Software Manager, it lets you search for things and browse from the comfort of a GUI, but it's slower than using a terminal.